# How to registeractivity in manifest.xml

Tags: android

I am green hand in android studio.How can I register activities in Manifest.xml,why always get wrong in the name??

[image]

Comment: which activity return error?? 
mainactivity??

Comment: Put mouse into the error and check which is it?

Comment: You only have to write correct path of the activity. In Android Studio automatic suggestions will come for registering activity. But make sure you had extended your Activity  with Activity/ActionBarActivity/AppCompatActivity.

Answer (score 0):

Register activity in manifest like this  -

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.yourpackage.name.Activity_Register"
        />
```

Here - com.yourpackage.name is a package where your Activity file (class) Actvity_Register is place. Put this always inside Application tag of manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

Actually even though it displays in red.when you run it can run perfectly.
If you want to rectify it just add your package name before the activity name.Like
`com.example.android.broadcastbestpractice.LoginActivity`

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

For you:

```
< activity android:name="[your package of Activity_Register class].Activity_Register"></ activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

First Clean your project or restart Android Studio then give the path to main Acitvity using alt+space

For launcher activity you can register your activity like this:

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

For simple other activity you can register your activity:

```
 <activity
                android:name=".Testactivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >

            </activity>
```